# How eos prevent contract upgrade for evil?

Tags: smart-contract

Can the publisher do evil with upgrading the smart contract?
In eos, the smart contract is controlled by an account.

Answer (score 4):

Best practices will emerge over time but it is already possible to set permissions up in such a way that a `setcode` action *must* be delayed by some period of time before it can be applied.

The important part of this is that it must be published *to the chain* before the delay countdown can begin.  This means as a dApp user you can look for and find how long you have to "Exit" the dApp if a pending `setcode` is published and you don't like the incoming code.

Think of it like a TTL on a DNS record.